# bitmap to movie?

Tags: c++, windows, performance, bitmap, gdi

I want to make little high-performance recording application.  For capturing, I will be using [the GDI way.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen)  However, I am not sure which method to use [to convert](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen) bitmaps to a movie.
I want to use the method that won't need to install any additional codecs or libaries on the PC where I record the movie.

Also, I am wondering which is the faster way to handle conversion from bitmap to movie. 
Is it faster to capture a bitmap and then add it to the movie from same thread, or is it faster to have one thread to capture bitmaps and another thread to add them to the movie?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20091018230333/http://gpalem.web.officelive.com/createmovie.html)

Comment: omg none is really reading my question :(

Comment: Please, the link I posted is referred as a source from the "tutorial" you linked, yet it is offline. I posted a link that use a web archive. It clearly show how to create uncompressed videos in avi containers using a simple library called cAviFile.

Comment: You can find cAviFile [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads163/sourcecode/multimedia/vfw/742887/CreateAvi/AviFile.h__.htm) and [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads183/sourcecode/embed/860190/AviFile.cpp__.htm).

Comment: Does that need any library installed on the PC where i record ?

Comment: It seem to use the AVIFile library, that is exposed by Avifil32.dll from Windows 2000 upward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own video encoders would be a lot of work. Why can't you use open-source solutions to do the encoding, such as ffmpeg or mencoder?

Comment: Did you read my question correctly or i dont understand something, here these methods looks easy to implement -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen

Comment: Yes that looks simple. But that's the capturing process, not the encoding (as H.264, mpgeg, or whatever format) process. That's why I recommended you use an existing solution for the encoding process, after you captured the screen.